# Availability Zone and Account Mapping

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm doing some research on AWS and I'm reading the documentation. I read this section four times, but I still don't get it.

> To ensure that resources are distributed across the Availability Zones for a region, we independently map Availability Zones to names for each AWS account. For example, the Availability Zone us-east-1a for your AWS account might not be the same location as us-east-1a for another AWS account.
>
> To coordinate Availability Zones across accounts, you must use the AZ ID, which is a unique and consistent identifier for an Availability Zone. For example, use1-az1 is an AZ ID for the us-east-1 Region and it has the same location in every AWS account.

So they want the resources distributed across the AZs and they do this by mapping?

Is it saying that an account will only automatically create resources in a single AZ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what the cited part means is that of each of the AWS accounts, there's a specific mapping of names of AZs like `us-east-1a` to actual, physical AZs, which might result of `us-east-1a` in one AWS account not being the same exact datacenter as `us-east-1a` on different AWS account and in part yes, it's there to more or less evenly distribute clients over all AZs. To answer second question - it's not so obvious, because deciding on creating resources in different AZs lies in user's hands - if you don't care about potential failures, you will be fine with creating all of your resources in one AZ, but you might very well be very strict about availability of your services and, for example, you might want to launch them in multiple AZs (but that will also mean more costs for you).

Answer (score 2):

AWS randomizes the labels associated with each availability zone across account boundaries, so my us-east-2a and your us-east-2a may be different from each other.  They are both in the us-east-2 region but they may not actually be the same AZ.

They do this to avoid the implications of human tendencies to associate significance with the labels (e.g. tendencies toward choosing the "first" or the "last" or the "newest" or the "oldest" zone when placing workloads) which could result in uneven demand for resources across the zones within the region by the customer base as a whole.

In one single account, us-east-2a always refers to the same availability zone.

You only have to take this fact into consideration if you are using multiple accounts and want to ensure that the workloads are together in the same AZ (for latency or VPC privatelink mapping purposes) or separated into different AZs (for failure isolation).